# Issues in combining HTML code and markdown code

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have started using markdown to write an ebook as it is easy to generate EPUB and other file formats.  However, I have started combining `HTML` code into `markdown` (`pandoc`), as markdown has some limited vocabulary.

For instance, I have been using the following HTML code to resize the image and its caption into `introduction.markdown` file.

```
 <figure>
    <img src="images/industry40-final.png" class="center"/>
     <figcaption class="caption">Figure 1.5 Industry 4.0 - the fourth industrial revolution.</figcaption>
    <figure>
```

My `.css` file is the following

```
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then, I use the following command to generate the EPUB file.

```
"C:\Program Files\Pandoc\pandoc.exe" -s --toc -c css-file.css -o ebook.epub title.txt chapter1.txt chapter2.markdown
```

My problem is the generated EPUB changes its formatting style right after the image in the document (the text right after image in the document becomes center aligned). Second, some paragraph right after text disappear.

What is the reason for this? how could I fix it?

Comment: I would try debugging this with calibre ebook viewer or similar (there you have browser-like dev tools). Also, for that case you don't need raw HTML. See the [implicit_figures](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-implicit_figures) extension, which is already turned on by default.

Comment: @mb21: Thanks for the suggestions. the implicit_figures serves the purpose. However, it seems that it is not the solution as I need to format text with advanced features such as center alignment of the figure caption and other features.  I have been using Adobe Digital Editors to view my EPUB file.

Comment: Markdown is just a nicer syntax for (a subset of) HTML. You use CSS to style HTML. I don't know ADE very well. But here's how I would debug this, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools (which is available in e.g. https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/viewer.html)